# SQL Server : filtering though large set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 1000 rows in which I want to check if these records exits in the table as follows

```
select * 
from table 
where ID in ('TS145698', 'TF58964', 'TG47896', 'TS12369')
```

If I enter 1000 ID's, I retrieve data for 786, how do I know which of the 214 IDs are not located in the table?

Comment: Put those 1000 ID's in a temp table. Do NOT EXISTS.

Comment: And if you do not care about NULL on the ID, then NOT IN.

Answer (score 1):

You can with a template table.

```
DECLARE @Template TABLE (ID NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Template
VALUES
 ('TS145698'),
 ('TF58964'),
 ('TG47896'),
 ('TS12369')

 SELECT * 
 FROM 
    @Template A LEFT JOIN
    table B ON A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE
    B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: if i had to filter this in excel instead of creating a temp_table?

Comment: @doe Sorry What do you mean?

Comment: im just thinking would it be easier if i take the records that i have and try to match them in excel ?

Comment: @doe Yes, you can find differ with `excel functions` also

Answer (score 1):

You can create table for criteria values, and then make a left join to main table:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM  [YourCriteriasTable] AS A 
LEFT JOIN [table] AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

And your wanted ID-s will have null values in B.* Fields.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to enter these values into a table parameter, cte, or temporary table, and then use left join with the actual table.
Another way is to use the values clause:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE 
(
    Id int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)
```

The query:

```
SELECT v.Id
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (5), (6)) AS v(Id) -- Use this instead of the IN operator
LEFT JOIN @T T ON v.Id = T.Id
WHERE T.Id IS NULL
```

Results:

```
Id
-----------
5
6
```

Another option is to use `UNION` to create you values list:

```
SELECT v.Id
FROM (
    SELECT 1 As Id
    UNION 
    SELECT 2
    UNION 
    SELECT 3
    UNION 
    SELECT 4
    UNION 
    SELECT 5
    UNION 
    SELECT 6
) AS v -- Use this instead of the IN operator

LEFT JOIN @T T ON v.Id = T.Id
WHERE T.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: i have a 1000 ids to filter

Comment: 1000 or 5 doesn't matter. You must use these values as a data source - so either use a temporary table, table variable, values clause, a cte or a derived table. I would have included the table variable version but Neer was faster then me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that:

```
select * from table where ID not in 
            ('TS145698'
             ,'TF58964'
             ,'TG47896'
             ,'TS12369'
             )
```

Comment: i tried this,but it just keeps on executing and gives me back multiple data,which is more that 214 records, it gives me back like 20 000 rows

Comment: @doe - so your table must have more than 1000 records in total.  Are you saying that you have a particular 1000 records, and you want to know which of those are not in the list of IDs?  In which case you need to select the 1000, then ...AND where ID not in...etc

Comment: first i wanted to check what Ids are in the table, with the in clause i now know which ones they are, how ever now i dont know which ones are not in that list of the 1000 ids that i am filtering for

Comment: @doe - how do you obtain the 1000 rows that you are interested in?